# Calling a REST API, I get a "No Data Received" message inside my console but am able to authenticate

Tags: c#, rest

I don't know if I'm passing the Parameters and Headers correctly or not. I am getting no data back.

ive added ParatmeterType.GetOrPost and Parametertype.RequestBody to each parameter as well.

```
var userName = "**************";
var password = "***************";       
var client = new RestClient("API/source");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password);  
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("request_token", "testrequesttoken");
request.AddParameter("tool_version", "testtoolversion");
request.AddParameter("tool_License", "testlicense");
request.AddParameter("engine_serial", "testserial");
request.AddParameter("veh_vin", "testvin");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I am able to Authenticate but am getting no Data back.

Comment: What is the data you are expecting to receive?

Comment: if the SQL server I am calling is Updated successfully I should get a response of "True"

Comment: And if its not updated successfully, should you get `false`?

Comment: Any other returns aside from "True" would indicate Error.

Comment: Are you returning the error?

Comment: No, I am very new to this.

Comment: So that's why you're getting no data back then... the SQL server update command is likely not working as you expect and you're not returning any errors etc and so you get no data back. Try returning the errors and see if you get anything back from the API request.